# Python container requests are not resolving locally

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to make a request from a python container instance to an endpoint on the NodeJS server, but my requests are not resolving to localhost and are being routed to my corp proxy. (Docker proxy bypass has already been set to localhost and 127.0.0.0/8).

Docker setup:

```
IMAGE                 COMMAND                       PORTS                                        NAMES
redis:alpine          "docker-entrypoint.s…"        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                       redis
pyserver              "flask run"                   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                       pyserver
nodeserver            "npm start"                   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp   nodejs_server
postgres:10           "docker-entrypoint.s…"        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                       database
```

My python server is setup using Flask, and I have set a route (let's say "/views") with a function which will make a request to a specific endpoint on nodejs_server.

For example:

```
r.get("http://nodejs_server:80/endpoint")
```

but when visiting this endpoint on the browser or also via CURL from the pyserver container (curl -X GET http://pyserver/views), the container is making an outbound request rather than resolving to localhost:80.

All the containers are on the same network, and the docker proxy bypass is already configured. Pyserver has no issues connecting to the redis container by hostname (redis.Redis(host="redis", port=6379)).

I have tried using aiohttp and requests libraries and both fail to resolve nodejs_server to localhost. Am I doing something wrong or are the python libraries always going to make requests to external?

The docker network they are on is a bridged network.

Comment: A quick question and sorry if I have inferred incorrectly - Are you using the hosts as - http://nodejs_server:80 and http://pyserver, assuming they will resolve to localhost?

Comment: @Saurabh Yeah pyserver is running on localhost:5000 and nodejs_server is on localhost:80. There are no conflicting ports, but for some reason all the python HTTP requests are automatically being queried outbound and not to localhost. Ie. my corp proxy is not resolving localhost requests.

Comment: Use http://0.0.0.0/endpoint

Comment: @Saurabh I have tried that, doesnt work either.